# If Conditional with two roles

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, roles

I have been trying but I do not achieve results.
I wish that only the author of the post and the users with the shop_manager role can see it, if not redirect the page. If they are authors but they didnt write the post, they wont be able to access it.

the code works for everything except shop_manager users can see it.

```
  function wpso_author_redirection() {
if ( is_single() ) {
    $current_post_details = get_post( get_the_ID(), ARRAY_A );
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id != absint( $current_post_details['post_author']) ||$user 
  ['roles']!= 'shop_manager'  )   {
         wp_redirect( 'https://aa.com/contenido-bloqueado');
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: That will allow anyone who is not the author to see it. PHP has lazy expression evalutation, so when the current user is not the author (and the first part of the expression evaluates to true) anything to the left of the `||` will not be evaluated.

Comment: so..How i can do?can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innermost if statement, you are using || . This means OR and it means that if user is not the author or user role is not shop_manager, the redirection is going to execute.

You have to use AND, && in php:

```
if ($user_id != absint( $current_post_details['post_author']) && $user['roles']!= 'shop_manager'  )   {
    wp_redirect( 'https://aa.com/contenido-bloqueado');
}
```

this AND says that if the user is not the author and the user role is not shop_manager then do the redirect. If whatever of the two is false (user is author or user role is shop_manager) the redirect is not going to execute.

Comment: you could explain why, so OP knows next time :)

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answers. the first condition `!=absint( $current_post_details['post_author'])` works. but the second no. may be it could it cancel the rest?
author role: this role writes post
shop_manager this role does not write post you can only see all the post

Comment: maybe the $user variable is empty. you can check it with `var_dump($user)`. 
if it's empty, you need to fill it with the user data with `$user = wp_get_current_user()` before the if statement. You will find the roles in an array with $user->roles so your if statement could be `&& in_array('shop_manager', $user->role)`

Comment: Great it is work with the variable or. Thanks!!! Can you modify your answer for mark it?